# How to make Location Wise Customer Data as in Google Analytics with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to make a map just like in Google Analytics to show the number of users registered from different locations. For some reasons I'm not using the Google analytics. Can anyone Help me out without using Google analytics? Technologies I'm using are MVC, C#, Sql Server-2014, AngularJS, Jquery. I've been searching for a while now, but I only get solutions with google analytics.

PS:- I don't know how to start so can't put on any code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some WEB APIs for user location might be useful.
When user registered, send it to the backend.

1. Get the user location

   `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`

   ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition
2. Display it on the map, there are lots of way to display a map in frontend.

   2-1) Google Map API
    
       ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

   2-2) OpenStreetMap - many libraries in OSM, here is Mapbox.
    
       ref: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/centering-markers/

Comment: Thanks. But I need to show the number of users for any location or city. Do you have any link for that?

Comment: Can clusters help you? https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/filtering-marker-clusters/

Comment: but clusters is about display data. https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/filtering-marker-clusters/
I don't know if there is a easy way to collect number of users in certain location.

Comment: I'm lost right now. Let me grab some pieces and get back to you.